# Problema no WhereIn utilizando array

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Tenho um sistema na qual preciso listar alguns funcionários. Essa listagem vai depender do código de departamento do supervisor.

Ex: Se o supervisor for do departamento 206, ele poderá acessar todos os dados dos servidores dos departamentos: (205,206,207,209);

Por isso, estou tentando fazer uma query utilizando WhereIn e passando como parâmetro um array. Porém, não estou obtendo êxito. Não sei como resolver essa situação.

Portanto vou explicar abaixo como funciona essa parte do sistema para vocês conseguirem me ajudar se possível.

A função **lotacaoSaude** serve para retornar um array dos departamentos que o supervisor poderá acessar.

```
$dep = Session::get('dep');

$deps = lotacaoSaude($dep);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo é a forma que monto minha query:

```
$servidores = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
        ->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
        ->select('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*')
        ->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','10')
        ->whereIN('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento',[$deps])
        ->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia', '8')
        ->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
        ->orderby('sch_decom.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Da maneira que fiz apresenta o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Vale lembrar que a coluna cd_departamento no banco de dados é do tipo **integer**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do Laravel [Where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) o método `whereIn` verifica se dada coluna está contida em dada array.

O exemplo dado na documentação é:

```
   $users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```

Deixando claro que nesse caso o método `whereIn` ira compara o valor da coluna `id` com `1`, `2` ou `3` e retornará o registro somente se 'id' for igual a um desses valores.

No seu caso `$deps` já é uma array então fazer `[$deps]` equivale a criar um array cujo o seu único elemento é uma array.

```
[$deps] == [ [205, 206, 207, 209] ];
```

Então usar`whereIn`com o parâmetro `[$deps]`:

```
->whereIn('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', [$deps])
```

Equivale a :

```
->whereIn('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', [ [205, 206, 207, 209] ])
```

Ou seja somente seria retornada o registro cujo o departamento fosse o array `[205, 206, 207, 209]` o que não deve existir no seu banco de dados.

Presumindo que sua consulta esteja correta e somente a grafia de `whereIn`, `orderBy` e a array de consulta estivessem comprometidos, o código deve ficar assim:

```
$servidores = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
        ->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
        ->select('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*')
        ->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','10')
        ->whereIn('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', $deps)
        ->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia', '8')
        ->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Obrigado Augusto.